# Compared declared variable to int constant and it shows error "result of comparison with Boolean expression always true" - WHY is this Boolean?

Tags: c, cs50

Disclaimer: I'm a newbie.
I was trying out conditional chains in C with a simple quiz.

I entered this:

```
int age = get_int("Age in whole numbers: ");

        int r;
        if(age<12)
        {
            printf("Go back kid\n");
            r = 0;
        }
        else if(12<= age <16)
        {
            printf("Teenagers not allowed\n");
            r = 0;
        }
```

(im using cs50 codespace in visualstudio which has aforementioned get_int function)

age<12 worked but problem showed with this line

```
  else if(12<= age <16)
```

The error mentioned in title: [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kb7zm.jpg)

My main question is the "why" and not just the "how" - as in how does this result in a "Boolean expression" in this case?? I just want to check if age is greater than or equal to 12, and less than 16. The age variable is declared int and will store an int and not Boolean as per my current understanding.
How else do I compare the variable input?

Comment: You cannot use compound comparisons in C. Use `12 <= age && age > 16`

Comment: Try going over it from left to right. '12 <= age' results in a boolean. Is 'boolean' < 16? Why yes. Yes, it is, because it's always 0 or 1. So the condition is always 'true'.

Answer (score 1):

You want

```c
12 <= age && age < 16
```

or

```c
age >= 12 && age < 16
```

---

```c
12 <= age < 16
```

means

```c
( 12 <= age ) < 16
```

`12 <= age` is `0` or `1` depending on the value of `age`, so you end up with

```c
0 < 16
```

or

```c
1 < 16
```

So your condition is always true.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write "math-style" comparisons, the comparison operators are strictly binary (compare two things, left-hand and right-hand sides) so you end up doing

```
else if ((12 <= age) < 16)
```

since the first `<=` results in 0 or 1, it's always less than 16 which is always true.

Instead I would write it as:

```
else if (age >= 12 && age < 16)
```

I think that's easier to read, with the variable on the left on both comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

`12 <= age` is a 'boolean expression', which means it will convert `12 <= age` to a boolean (`true` or `false`).
In C `false = 0` and `true = 1`.
So if you write it differently:

1. `(12 <= age < 16)`
2. `(true < 16)` or `(false < 16)`
3. `(1 < 16)` or `(0 < 16)`
4. `true` or `true`

What you have to do is split it up into the individual expressions.

`(12<= age <16)` --> `(12 <= age && age < 16)`